# Atlas exporting in pdf/A using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pdf, atlas

Is there a way to print an atlas in a pdf/A file for each page, being pdf/A an international standard?

I'm using QGIS 2.18.

Comment: Based on [this discussion about converting a pdf to pdf/a](https://superuser.com/questions/188953/how-to-convert-a-pdf-to-a-pdf-a), it seems that simply rasterizing your output should do the job, since it will eliminate the need for any outside content like non-embedded fonts or linked images. At least that's my best understanding of the concept, based on spending about five minutes reading about it. :) Looking forward to seeing what other people have to say.